# How to setup EXPECT_CALL on a const method?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I want to setup an `EXPECT_CALL` using GMock for following method:

```
class Foo {
    virtual void Bar() const;
};
```

I define the respective Gmock class as below:

```
class MockFoo : public Foo {
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(Bar, void());
};
```

Then, of course, I have the objects of these classes.

```
Foo myFoo;
MockFoo myMockFoo;
```

In the test, I declare an `EXPECT_CALL` as below:

```
EXPECT_CALL(myFoo, Bar);
```

This doesn't work, and I get a compilation error:

```
'class Foo' has no member named 'gmock_Bar'
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to `EXPECT_CALL` on the `const` method. What I am doing wrong here?

I have looked into the [Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md) and [Cook Book](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md), but couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

*This error was an oversight on my part due to a wrong copy-paste from existing code at my workplace. I will share this with the community so that it may help someone in future from frustration and wasting time.*

This error has nothing to do with `const`ness of the method, but it is because of the incorrect 1st argument to `EXPECT_CALL`. Change it from `myFoo` to `myMockFoo` to setup the expectation correctly.

The generated Mock function is a member of the Mock class `MockFoo`, not the actual class `Foo`. Hence, the mock object should be passed to `EXPECT_CALL`.

Comment: Does it work when you set an expectation on `MockFoo`, _the class_ instead of an instance?

Comment: @AntonioPérez That's a good catch. It needs an instance rather than a class. I was sloppy in redacting the code in both the question and the answer, I will edit this later.